# Reverse Engineering Insert Scripts in MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

I have a table that I have inserted data into. It has been a tedious process.I wanted to see 
if i could reverse engineering the INSERT INTO statements as I still don't have a working script to import the database so that I could use this in different development environments.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Comment: You can try [SQLyog trial](http://webyog.com/en/downloads.php) or [SQLyog Community](http://code.google.com/p/sqlyog/downloads/list). There is an option "Backup Database as SQL dump" which would suit your purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the SQLyog trial. It defintely worked! I am hoping there is a tool inside this that takes an Excel spreadsheet and directly copies the data. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Workbench will create insert scripts for you using the "forward engineer" option and selecting the "create insert statements" option.  If you are using OSX I recommend a free program called Sequel Pro.  It has a great tool for copying table data as insert statements.  You can also write a select statement that outputs the "values" part of the insert.  Then paste its results below the INSERT INTO part of the statement.  For serious exporting you can always use mysqldump.

```
SELECT "('", myField1, "','", myField2,"')," FROM myTable
```